# Stereographic projection to the torus in R^3 plus infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I'm reading a book about algebraic geometry. I quote a portion of the book, with a few modifications.

"Let $=(^2−^3)$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$,

using stereographic projection

all points on $X$ can be written uniquely as $=^3,=^2 (∈)$

so $(,)∈\partial B \iff ||^2+||^2=1 \iff ||^6+||^4 = 1$

i.e., $||=$ where $$ is the unique positive solution of $^6+^4=1$

Thus, $∩ \partial = $locus of points $(^3^{3},^2^{2})$

Under Stereographic projection $\mathbb{C}^2⊃∂⟶\mathbb{R}^3∪\{\infty\},(,)↦(\frac{ℑ}{1−ℜ},\frac{ℜ}{1−ℜ},\frac{ℑ}{1−ℜ})$,

it is easy to see that

the torus $=\{||=,||=,^2+^2=1\} \subset \partial B$

goes over to the torus $T'=\{(,,)|^2+(\sqrt{^2+^2}−\frac{1}{})^2=(\frac{}{})^2\}$

where the angular cooridnates $\arg x$, $\arg y$ on $$ correspond to the angular coordinates $\phi$,$\psi$ on $T'$(*)

---

I wanted to show (*).

Let $u = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\sin\phi, v = (\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cos\phi + \frac{1}{\beta})\cos\psi ,w = (\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cos\phi + \frac{1}{\beta})\sin\psi$.

Then $\frac{w}{v} = \frac{\sin \psi}{cos\psi} = \tan \psi
 $ and, $\frac{w}{v} =\frac{\Im y}{\Re y} = \tan (\arg y) $

so $\arg y$ on $$ correspond to the angular coordinates $\psi$

But I couldn't show correspondence of $\arg x$ and $\phi$ using this parametric display.

Can anyone give me some tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two inequivalent ways to parametrize a circular torus here:

- The stereographic parametrization
  $$
  x(\phi, \psi) = \frac{(\alpha\cos\phi, \alpha\sin\phi, \beta\cos\psi)}{1 - \beta\sin\psi};
  $$
- The common circular parametrization
  $$
  y(\phi, \psi) = \bigl((R + r\cos\phi)\cos\psi, (R + r\cos\phi)\sin\psi, r\sin\phi\bigr).
  $$
  The first (blue) is the image of the Clifford torus
  $$
  X(\phi, \psi) = (\alpha\cos\phi, \alpha\sin\phi, \beta\cos\psi, \beta\sin\psi)
  $$
  under stereographic projection from the unit sphere. The second (green) has the same image if the major radius $R$ and minor radius $r$ satisfy
  $$
  R + r = \frac{\alpha}{1 - \beta},\qquad
  R - r = \frac{\alpha}{1 + \beta}.
  $$
  The parametrizations are not the same, however; the first is conformal while the second has "equally-spaced" coordinate curves in the sense of Euclidean angles measured along circles.

[image: Stereographic and equi-angular tori]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the first parametrization. But in the book, $\phi$ and $\psi$ is written as the second parametrization in a cutaway view.

Comment: One doesn't like to accuse authors of errors when they have no way to respond, but a plot of the resulting trefoil knots visually confirms the first parametrization is meant.