# Calculating the intersection of $u^2 - v^3$ with a 3-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, mathematica, fibration, stereographic-projections

For context, I'm coding a 3D visualisation of the Milnor fibration of a Trefoil knot.

I've found some code [https://www.unf.edu/~ddreibel/research/milnor/milnor-fibers.nb](https://www.unf.edu/%7Eddreibel/research/milnor/milnor-fibers.nb) that calculates the intersection of the real and imaginary parts of $u^m - v^n$ with a 3-sphere radius $\sqrt2$, and stereographically projects this to $\mathbb{R}^3$. I don't understand the following substitution into $(x + iy)^m - (z + iw)^n$ (presumably to calculate the intersection):

$$x \rightarrow \frac{\sqrt2 (-2+x^2+y^2+z^2)}{2+x^2 + y^2 + z^2}, y \rightarrow \frac{4x}{2+x^2 + y^2 + z^2},z \rightarrow \frac{4y}{2+x^2 + y^2 + z^2},w \rightarrow \frac{4z}{2+x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$
after which the expression is multiplied by $(2+x^2+y^2+z^2)^{Max(m,n)}$

Any insights on how this works, or are there any alternative methods?

Comment: Of course, you mean $u^2=v^3$ ... with $(u,v)$ coordinates on $\Bbb C^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix coprime positive integers $m$ and $n$. What I'd do (not having looked at the linked code) is parametrize the knot $\{(u, v) \in \mathbf{C}^{2} : u^{m} - v^{n} = 0\} \cap S^{3}(\sqrt{2})$ by $\gamma(t) = (e^{int}, e^{int})$, split each component into real and imaginary parts,
$$
\gamma(t) = (\cos(nt), \sin(nt), \cos(mt), \sin(mt)) = (x, y, z, w),
$$
and stereographically project to three-space, obtaining (modulo permutation of coordinates)
$$
\Gamma(t) = \frac{\sqrt{2}(x, y, z)}{\sqrt{2} - w}
= \frac{\sqrt{2}(\cos(nt), \sin(nt), \cos(mt))}{\sqrt{2} - \sin(mt)}.
$$

(This is indeed [different](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4429555/stereographic-projection-to-the-torus-in-r3-plus-infinity) from Jyrki's parametrization, which comes from the standard circular torus
$$
x(u, v) = ((R + r\cos u)\cos v, (R + r\cos u)\sin v, r\sin u)
$$
by restricting to a line of slope $n/m$ in the $(u, v)$ plane.)

[image: A three-sphere trefoil knot projected to Euclidean three-space]

Comment: Thanks. Let's wait for the OP to also comment. If you don't mind me asking, Is the mesh in your image the Seifert surface? Does its parametrization also come from this?

Comment: Hmm. Checking out the thread you linked to while experimenting with Mathematica I now think that the surface comes from letting $\phi=2t,\psi=3t$ with $t$ ranging over $[0,2\pi]$ AND letting  $(\alpha,\beta)=(\cos v,\sin v)$ with $v\in[0,\pi/4]$. At least the choice of $v$ gives a family of trefoil curves when $v>0$. The limit case $v=0$ gives a doubled curve on the plane $z=0$.

Comment: First of all, thank you Jyrki for shedding more light on the problem, since then I've tinkered around and gotten the plot I needed but I'm still not sure where the surface comes from - this answer actually solves the other half of my problem which was deriving the trefoil boundary so thanks again.

Comment: Dissecting the code further, if we let the real and imaginary parts of $u^2 - v^3$ with the above substitution be f and g respectively, and $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$, $f\cos(\theta) + g\sin(\theta) = 0$ obtains [this plot](https://imgur.com/a/97QhGap) (with the knot boundary plotted) and if we further say $f\sin(\theta) - g\cos(\theta) > 0$ we get [this plot](https://imgur.com/a/sgfx6Pp). Still not sure on how any of this works...

Comment: @Jyrki The mesh is the stereographically-projected graph of the cusp,$$x(r,t)=\frac{\sqrt{2}(r^2\cos(2t),r^2\sin(2t),r^3\cos(3t))}{\sqrt{2} - r^3\sin(3t)},\quad0\leq r\leq 1,\ 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi,$$which seemed worth including both as one of the intersecting objects, and (mostly) because it makes the spatial structure of the knot easier to see. :)

Comment: @user83893939 As you may know, the mapping in the question is inverse stereographic projection with the pole at $(\sqrt{2},0,0,0)$. Separately, it appears the $(x, y, z, w)$ on the left, a.k.a. the real and imaginary parts of $(u, v)$, are not the $(x, y, z)$ on the right, which are Cartesian coordinates in three-space. Modulo this, the four equations implicitly define the Euclidean image of a knot in $S^3(\sqrt{2})$. <> If this answer doesn't address your primary question please do say so; I'm happy to delete it temporarily until the bounty expires.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang That definitely solves it, I wasn't aware of the inverse stereographic projection map but it makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!